# Ionic 3 setRoot NOT working on IOS device

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, device

i am testing a the hello world app on an iPhone4 device and some others devices with Android.

Ionic version 3.10.3

npm version 3.10.10

.

The main **huge** problem is with the iPhone device, the call to setRoot is not working. ("WORKS on Emulators")

```
void onGoClick(){
// this line **DOES NOTHING** and no error is thrown.

this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);


// this line **DOES NOTHING** and no error is thrown.

this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage);

// this line **DOES NOTHING** and no error is thrown.

this.app.getRootNav().setRoot("HomePage");
}
```

this also **DOES NOT WORK**

```
var root = this.appCtrl.getRootNav();
root.popToRoot();
root.setRoot( "HomePage" );
```

or without quotes `root.setRoot( HomePage );`

.

**but if i click the button twice it works....**

is like some refresh is missing....

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the iOS version, 4 is too old, if you test with an iPhone 6.

you can also try to run like this.

```
this.navCtrl.setRoot(DestinationPage).then( ()=>{
            this.navCtrl.popToRoot().then( ()=> {
            }).catch(err=>{
                TError.handleException( "err 2: ", err );

            });
        }).catch(err=>{

        });
```

Regards.

Comment: you can also try to run like this.

<code>
this.navCtrl.setRoot(DestinationPage).then( ()=>{
   this.navCtrl.popToRoot().then( ()=> {
   }).catch(err=>{
    TError.handleException( "err 2: ", err );
    
   });
  }).catch(err=>{

  });
</code>